# How to make timeout operator fire exception one time in RxJava2 (RxJava3) chain before retry

Tags: generics, kotlin, timeout, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to extend functionality of my custom `FlowableTransformer` which I use to conditionally switch from one `Flowable` to another, returned by provided `Function<T, Flowable<R>>`, i.e. in my `switchFunction` I send an item to server and switch to a server response flowable if initial item matches some condition:

```
/**
 * Switches from upstreamFlowable to anotherFlowable
 * using switchFunction if item from upstreamFlowable
 * matches test condition
 *
 * usage:
 *       upstreamFlowable
 *       .compose(RxSwitchFlowablesOnCondition(condition, switchFunction))
 **/
open class
RxSwitchFlowablesOnCondition<T, R>(private val condition : Predicate<T>,
                                   private val switchFunction : Function<T, Flowable<R>>) : FlowableTransformer<T, R>
{
  override fun
  apply(upstreamFlowable : Flowable<T>) : Publisher<R>
  {
    return upstreamFlowable
    .compose(RxFlowableOnIo<T>())
    .filter {emittedItem : T ->
      condition.test(emittedItem)
    }
    .switchMap {emittedItem : T ->
      val anotherFlowable = switchFunction.apply(emittedItem)

      anotherFlowable
      //.timeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, SECONDS) // #1
    }
    //.timeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, SECONDS) // #2
  }
}
```

To restart the chain if error happens, in my android application I use `retry` operator:

```
upstreamFlowable
.compose(RxSwitchFlowablesOnCondition(condition, switchFunction))
.retry() // to resubscribe on error
.subscribe(...)
```

What I want to do is to add `timeout` logic, for example, if time between emitting an item by `upstreamFlowable` and obtaining the response in `anotherFlowable`is greater than `CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SECONDS`, I would like to fire an error and resubscribe to the `upstreamFlowable`, so that I could wait for next `emittedItem`.

What I have:

1. If I uncomment line `#1`,  then timeout produces a `TimeoutException`, retry resubscribes to chain and I continue to get timeout exceptions every `CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SECONDS` period of time even without next emitted items. **How to skip them?**
2. If I uncomment line `#2`, then I start to receive `TimeoutException`s after `CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SECONDS` since subscription, not since item emission. **How it can be fixed?**

Need your help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get behavior that you wanted, you only need small changes in your `switchMap` block. So, i modified your `apply` implementation into this

```
override fun
  apply(upstreamFlowable : Flowable<T>) : Publisher<R>
  {
    return upstreamFlowable
    .compose(RxFlowableOnIo<T>())
    .filter {emittedItem : T ->
      condition.test(emittedItem)
    }
    .switchMap {
        Flowable.just(it)
            .switchMap { emittedItem : T ->
                val anotherFlowable = switchFunction(emittedItem)

                 anotherFlowable
              }
             .timeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, SECONDS)
         }
  }
```

By doing it like this, `timeout` will start counting when value has been emitted.

**Update**
For testing, i've stage simple code and adding log:

1. upstream will emit once after 2 seconds
2. anotherFlowable will emit once after 1 second
3. timeout is 500 ms

// sample usage

```
val upstream = Flowable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        upstream
                .doOnSubscribe { println("subscribed ${System.currentTimeMillis()}") }
                .compose(
                        RxSwitchFlowablesOnCondition<Long, Long>(
                                Predicate { true },
                                { Flowable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)})
                )
                .doOnError { println("timeout ${System.currentTimeMillis()}") }
                .retry()
                .subscribe()
```

// RxSwitchFlowablesOnCondition

```
open class
    RxSwitchFlowablesOnCondition<T, R>(private val condition : Predicate<T>,
                                       private val switchFunction : (T) -> Flowable<R>) : FlowableTransformer<T, R>
    {
        override fun
                apply(upstreamFlowable : Flowable<T>) : Publisher<R>
        {
            return upstreamFlowable
                    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .filter {emittedItem : T ->
                        condition.test(emittedItem)
                    }
                    .switchMap {
                        Flowable.just(it)
                                .doOnNext { println("onNext ${System.currentTimeMillis()}") }
                                .switchMap { emittedItem : T ->
                                    val anotherFlowable = switchFunction(emittedItem)

                                    anotherFlowable
                                }
                                .timeout(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    }

        }
    }
```

and this is sample output log

```
subscribed 1569286225769
onNext 1569286227790
timeout 1569286228292  // around 500 ms after onNext
subscribed 1569286228295
onNext 1569286230297
timeout 1569286230800
subscribed 1569286230800
onNext 1569286232803
timeout 1569286233306
subscribed 1569286233306
```

Is it consistent with your expectation?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still start to receive TimeoutExceptions after CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_SECONDS since subscription, not since item emission.

Comment: I've add sample code to show that TimeoutExceptions happened after item emission. Is it consistent with your expectation?

Comment: Well, it really fires timeout after subscription and emitting next item. Thank you for your attention!